# How to get all users from assignment group in service now?While creating an INCIDENT i need to assign a User from the particular group

Tags: rest, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, community-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2jdL.png)

I dont know how did i get the assigned to as a sysId in the response. Please help me to know how do i find all the users of a particular group.?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your image the information for the groups is stored in table sys_user_group. The information which users are assigned to which group is stored in table sys_user_grmember. So the REST query could be a GET to this URL:

https://YOURINSTANCE.com/api/now/table/sys_user_grmember?sysparm_query=group%3DSYSIDOFUSERGROUP